# SQL statement to exclude certain rows of data

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT viewid, 
            relid, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtaap *. 01)  AS OPEN, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtcurr *. 01) AS CURRENT1, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtftr *. 01)  AS FUTURE, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtag1 *. 01)  AS AGE1, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtag2 *. 01)  AS AGE2, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtag3 *. 01)  AS AGE3, 
            rtcrcd, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtag4 *. 01)  AS AGE4, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtag5 *. 01)  AS AGE5, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtag6 *. 01)  AS AGE6, 
            Sum(kaiprddta.f0315le.rtag7 *. 01)  AS AGE7, 
            rtco 
FROM   kaiprddta.f0315le, 
   kaiprddta.f55311 
WHERE  ( kaiprddta.f0315le.rtac06 = terr ) 
   AND ( viewid = 'Company' ) 
   AND ( rtco = '00001' 
          OR rtco = '00099' ) 
GROUP  BY viewid, 
      relid, 
      rtcrcd, 
      rtco 
ORDER  BY viewid, 
      relid, 
      rtcrcd
```

Here's what it looks like now(I'm not allowed to embed images yet so if someone could edit it and make it embedded that would be awesome):

[image: Sample]

There is two RELID values "Region427" and "Region632" that both have 2 RTCO values "00001" and "00099".  All the other rows of data have one RTCO value of "00001". The sql returns one row of data per RTCO value. I want to only return the row for RTCO value "00099" for "Region427" and "Region632". Can someone help me to modify my sql statement to achieve this

Comment: FOr the two RelID's, Do you want RTCO 00001 and 00099 to be summed together, or do you just want to exclude RTCO 00001 entirely?

Comment: to exclude '00001' entirely, but just for Region427 and Region632. i just added a picture of what the data looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND ( (rtco = '00001' AND RELID!="Region427")
          OR (rtco = '00099' AND RELID="Region427"))
```

I believe is what you are after.

Ted.

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the '00001' row of data for Region427

Comment: @KMurray try <> instead

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much, I have been trying to do this forever!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAX(rtco) instead of rtco in your select statement, but it may not bring the relid and rtcrcd of this row having the max value of rtco

Comment: I can't use the max or min on this query because there is other values other than '00001' and '00099'

Comment: but the where condition will return only the values with  '00001' and '00099'  and then the MAX will pick the maximum one

Comment: There is a different row of data for each RTCO value, that's why I'm trying to exclude the data when RELID = 'REGION427' and RTCO = '00001' and RELID = 'REGION632' and RTCO = '00001'